# Explanation of struct ieee80211_local in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi

Can anybody explain me the `ieee80211_local` structure and its members?

The structure is defined in `/net/mac80211/ieee80211_i.h` of the Linux source code, somewhere near line no. 930, it may vary with different kernel versions.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a presentation by Daniel Camps Mur](http://www.campsmur.cat/files/mac80211_intro.pdf) `struct ieee80211_local` *"…contains information about the real hardware, and is created when the interface is first added."*

In another set of [slides by Johannes Berg](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=overview.pdf) it is stated that the struct  *"represents a wireless device."* On the same slide, you can find a statement about the element `ieee80211_hw` *"…is the part of `ieee80211_local` that is visible to drivers."*

Interestingly, the struct is not mentioned in the [802.11 subsystems documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/80211/index.html) by Johannes Berg.

Looking at a [source code cross reference of the Linux kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=ieee80211_local), you can see that the 
`ieee80211_local` struct is never used outside of the mac80211 part. Therefore, I think that it is indeed an internally used representation of a wireless device from mac80211's point of view.
In contrast, you can see that the `ieee80211_hw` element is [used in both mac80211 and various wireless device drivers](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=ieee80211_hw) which underlines that it is used to communicate between mac80211 and drivers.

BTW, the struct was introduced with the [very first commit of ieee80211_i.h](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/linville/wireless/+/f0706e828e96d0fa4e80c0d25aa98523f6d589a0/net/mac80211/ieee80211_i.h) by Jiri Benc in 2007.

If you need to know more details about the struct and its members, it looks like you want to do some development at the mac80211 code. I would suggest to get in touch with the active developers. The [Linux wireless mailing list](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/MailingLists) may be a good starting point for that.